# Action of $\operatorname{Aut}(A) \times \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ on $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{Aut}(A))$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $G$ and $A$ be two finite abelian groups. Let $T:= \operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{Aut}(A))$ be the set of all injective group homomorphisms from $G$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$.

Take $g := (\sigma,\rho)\in \operatorname{Aut}(A) \times \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and let $$T^g := \{\alpha \in T :\alpha \circ \rho = \gamma_{\sigma} \circ \alpha \}.$$
where $\gamma_{\sigma}$ denotes the conjugation by $\sigma$ in $Aut(A)$.
Are there some conditions on $G$ and $A$, or examples, under which we can compute easily the cardinality of $T^g$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $\gamma_\sigma$?

Comment: @azif00, thank you for your remark.  $\gamma_{\sigma}$ denotes the conjugation by $\sigma$ in $Aut(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just some very partial work, that I couldn't accomodate into a comment. So:

\begin{alignat}{1}
T^{(\sigma,\rho)} &:=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(\rho(g))=\sigma^{-1}\alpha(g)\sigma, \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid \sigma\alpha(\rho(g))=\alpha(g)\sigma, \space\forall g\in G\} \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

As special cases:

- $(\sigma,\rho)=(\iota_A,\iota_G)$

\begin{alignat}{1}
T^{(\iota_A,\iota_G)} &=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(g)=\alpha(g), \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&= T
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

- $(\sigma,\rho)=(\iota_A,\rho\ne\iota_G)$

\begin{alignat}{1}
T^{(\iota_A,\rho)} &=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(\rho(g))=\alpha(g), \space\forall g\in G\} \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

- $(\sigma,\rho)=(\sigma\ne\iota_A,\iota_G)$

\begin{alignat}{1}
T^{(\sigma,\iota_G)} &=\{\alpha\in T\mid \sigma\alpha(g)=\alpha(g)\sigma, \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(g)\in C_{\operatorname{Aut}(A)}(\sigma), \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(G)\le C_{\operatorname{Aut}(A)}(\sigma)\} \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I can't understand why $T^{(\iota_A,\rho)}$ is empty in the second case.

Comment: @NourrMga, you are right, in general it isn't as $\alpha$ in not in general bijective. I'm going to edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I well suppose now that   $T:= \operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{Aut}(A))$ is the set of all injective group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood anything, but if by "action" in the title you mean the following:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \mathcal{A}:(\operatorname{Aut}(A)\times\operatorname{Aut}(G))\times T & \longrightarrow & T \\
  ((\sigma,\rho),\alpha) & \longmapsto & (\sigma,\rho)\cdot\alpha: G & \longrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(A) \\
  && g &\longmapsto \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\sigma \\
\tag 0
\end{alignat*}

then seemingly it fails to fulfil the "Action#2" property for actions (see $(1)$ and $(2)$ hereunder). In that case, group actions wouldn't assist the matter.

---

- Good definition: for every $\sigma\in \operatorname{Aut}(A)$, $\rho \in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $g,h\in G$, indeed $\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\sigma\in \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ and:
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  ((\sigma,\rho)\cdot\alpha)(gh) &= \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(gh))\sigma \\
  &= \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g)\rho(h))\sigma \\
  &= \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\alpha(\rho(h))\sigma \\
  &= \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\sigma\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(h))\sigma \\
  &= (\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\sigma)(\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(h))\sigma) \\
  &= ((\sigma,\rho)\cdot\alpha)(g)((\sigma,\rho)\cdot\alpha)(h) \\
  \end{alignat}
  whence indeed $(\sigma,\rho)\cdot\alpha\in T$
- Action#1: $\forall \alpha\in T,\forall g\in G$,
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  ((\iota_A,\iota_G)\cdot\alpha)(g) &= \iota_A^{-1}\alpha(\iota_G(g))\iota_A \\
  &= \alpha(g) \\
  \end{alignat}
  whence $\forall\alpha\in T$:
  $$(\iota_A,\iota_G)\cdot\alpha=\alpha$$
- Action#2: $\forall \sigma,\sigma'\in\operatorname{Aut}(A),\forall \rho,\rho'\in\operatorname{Aut}(G), \forall \alpha\in T,\forall g\in G$,
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  (((\sigma,\rho)(\sigma',\rho'))\cdot\alpha)(g) &= ((\sigma\sigma',\rho\rho')\cdot\alpha)(g) \\
  &= (\sigma\sigma')^{-1}\alpha((\rho\rho')(g))\sigma\sigma' \\
  &= \sigma'^{-1}\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(\rho'(g)))\sigma\sigma' \\
  \tag 1
  \end{alignat}
  while
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  ((\sigma,\rho)\cdot((\sigma',\rho')\cdot\alpha))(g) &= \sigma^{-1}(((\sigma',\rho')\cdot\alpha)(\rho(g))\sigma \\
  &= \sigma^{-1}\sigma'^{-1}\alpha(\rho'(\rho(g))\sigma'\sigma \\
  \tag 2
  \end{alignat}
  Therefore, $\mathcal{A}$ defined in $(0)$ is not an action.

However, the map $\mathcal{A}$ becomes indeed an action if you narrow the group which acts on $T$ to $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(A))\times Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$, as in this case $(1)$ and $(2)$ match. In that case:

\begin{alignat}{1}
T^{(\sigma,\rho)} &:=\{\alpha\in T\mid \alpha(\rho(g))=\sigma\alpha(g)\sigma^{-1}, \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid \sigma^{-1}\alpha(\rho(g))\sigma=\alpha(g), \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid ((\sigma,\rho)\cdot \alpha)(g)=\alpha(g), \space\forall g\in G\} \\
&=\{\alpha\in T\mid (\sigma,\rho)\cdot \alpha=\alpha\} \\
&= \operatorname{Fix}(\sigma,\rho) \\
\end{alignat}

So, for instance, if you'd know that the action is transitive (so it had one orbit, only), then you could conclude that (Burnside's Lemma):

$$\sum_{(\sigma,\rho)\in Z(\operatorname{Aut}(A))\times Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))}|T^{(\sigma,\rho)}|=|Z(\operatorname{Aut}(A))\times Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))|$$

(I realized just now that I didn't take into accout the fact that $A$ and $G$ are finite abelian groups, by assumption, which should simplify this all...)

Comment: Yes the action in the title is as you defined it.

Comment: @NourrMga, but then that's seemingly not an action, as $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equal (for every $\sigma,\sigma',\rho,\rho',\alpha,g$).

Comment: @NourrMga, I've added some stuff. Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.